# What does "property" mean on this attribute?

Tags: c#, properties, attributes

```
[property: Obsolete]
static int X
{
    get { return 42; }
}
```

In the code above, what purpose does the word "property" serve? The code seems to work the same way if I replace [property: Obsolete] with [Obsolete]. And although "property" is coloured blue in Visual Studio, it does not appear in the list of C# keywords:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Attribute specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#attribute-specification) defines this as an `attribute target`.

> Certain contexts permit the specification of an attribute on more than
>   one target. A program can explicitly specify the target by including
>   an attribute_target_specifier. When an attribute is placed at the
>   global level, a global_attribute_target_specifier is required. In all
>   other locations, a reasonable default is applied, but an
>   attribute_target_specifier can be used to affirm or override the
>   default in certain ambiguous cases (or to just affirm the default in
>   non-ambiguous cases).

It also states that in many cases, like the one you mention, it is permitted but not necessary.

> In other contexts, inclusion of an attribute_target_specifier is
>   permitted but unnecessary. For instance, a class declaration may
>   either include or omit the specifier type.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [attribute target specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/attributes.md).

In your code the use of it is not really necessary, since there is just one allowed target for that attribute at that place. The `Obsolete` attribute can be placed on a type, method or a property, but if placed on a property, only the `property` target specifier is allowed (and used implicitly).

The most practical use for this is the `assembly` target specifier, where you can set assembly configuration through attributes:

```
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Foo bar")]
```

You can set the allowed targets on your custom attributes using `AttributeUsage`.